# How to show an image through an intent being compatible with different apps

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gmail, share

I'm trying to share an image I have previously saved on disk, sending an `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. The problem is that I can't find a way to be compatible with different apps, official Gmail app and TweetDeck in my case.

The image I want to share is contained in a `File`:

```
File agendaFile; 
// its path using getAbsolutePath() -> /data/data/com.mypackage/files/agenda.jpg
```

## Option A) using Uri.fromFile

```
Uri agendaUri = Uri.fromFile(agendaFile); 
// the value -> file:///data/data/com.mypackage/files/agenda.jpg
```

### Results

- Gmail, is the image attatched to the email? **NO**
- Tweetdeck, is the image added to the tweet message? **YES**

## Option B) using Uri.parse

```
Uri agendaUri = Uri.parse(agendaFile.toURI().toString()); 
// the value -> file:/data/data/com.mypackage/files/agenda.jpg
```

### Results

- Gmail, is the image attatched to the email? **YES**
- Tweetdeck, is the image added to the tweet message? **NO**

## Finally

In both cases I send the intent like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpg");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, agendaUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title"));
```

So, is there any other options to share an image? How is it the best way to share an image being compatible with most apps as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem storing the image at the MediaStore. Instead of using the URI of the File what I do is:

```
String agendaFilename = agendaFile.getAbsolutePath();

final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, agendaFilename);
final Uri contentUriFile = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

And finally I use `contentUriFile`:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpg");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUriFile);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title"));
```

Comment: I think you need to change the following line:
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
to:
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");

image/jpg is not a proper MIME type and that will cause the image not to be passed to the intent properly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Had similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031587/facebook-doesnt-appear-on-share-windows-when-trying-to-share-an-image/18033281#18033281) and your way solved my problem.
Do you know whats the problem with Uri.formfile that doesnt send the image on facebook?

Comment: what agendaFile? i am getting error in cannot resolve

Comment: agendaFile is the File representing the image I want to share in the intent

Answer (score 3):

try

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

for me it works for twitter, whatsapp, bluetooth....

EDIT: full code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, R.string.visita);
        Uri uri = Uri
        .parse("android.resource://com.package.xname/drawable/"
                + i);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: It has the same results for me. Which way do you use to get the uri from a File?

Comment: i am using the ressources (my pic in in drawable folder) that's maybe the difference, see EDIT

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. I've tried and still having same problem. As you suggest the difference could be my image is from disk and I'm doing something wrong building the uri. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

this code is more easy

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"XXXXX@XXXX.com");
            intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "XXXXX");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "XXXXX");
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            chosser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Enviar Email");
            intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(chosser);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me using FileProvider worked out. I had it set up for taking photos with built-in camera and used it for sharing (see below).

```
final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, "com.paeuba.paragonik.fileprovider", photoFile);
Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(mActivity).setType("image/jpeg").setStream(uri).createChooserIntent();
mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```