# Facebook Doesn't appear on share windows when trying to share an Image

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, bitmap, share

I create a bitmap in my app and want to share it via email apps or Facebook using Intent.ACTION_SEND.
the share window opens and gmail and yahoomail apps icon appear but no facebook or g+! I really doesn't know what's the problem. There is another problem that gmail app cannot attach the file (created from bitmap). I read a few similar questions but still I'm stocked. Help me please.

here is my code for sharing:

```
private  static File writePhotoPng(Bitmap data, String pathName) {
    File file = new File(pathName);
    try {

        file.createNewFile();
        // BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(
        // new FileOutputStream(file));
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}

public static void ShareOnFb(Bitmap share, Activity activity, String emailSubject){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    // EDIT:
    // !!! childish mistake. below line is correct !!! intent.setType("Image/*");
    intent.setType("image/*");
    //add data to intent, the receiving app will decide what to do with it.

    // email subject:
    if (emailSubject != null && !emailSubject.equals("")){
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
    }



    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(writePhotoPng(share, "temp.png")));

    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share on"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after correcting my childish mistake (see EDIT part in question) and Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969289/how-to-show-an-image-through-an-intent-being-compatible-with-different-apps) code snippet I finally solved this problem.

if anybody knows whats the difference between using `contentValue` and my approach please share that with me.

Comment: help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook